# Tire alignment and rotation - still pulls to the right

Tags: tires, alignment

Legacy 2017. bought with 26k miles and on a highway found out that car pulls to the right so I had to compensate with a steering to the left a little bit. Dealership made an alignment but it still pulled to the right. Came back to the dealer and they made a tire rotation claiming that previous owner failed rotating tires properly. Also they told me that during my next planned rotation the issue should be resolved....

I don't get it.... If car was pulling to the right - they made a rotation, shouldn't car not be pulling to the left? Which scenario could it be that car was pulling to the right, they made a rotation, car still pulls to the right but now the issue is being self-fixed so on the next rotation everything would be good. Thoughts?

Comment: I suggest getting an alignment done - the car may have hit the curb, damaging the suspension at some time. Rule that out as that is a common cause.

Comment: I'd take it somewhere else for an alignment check. If they're claiming misalignment, go back to the dealer. End of the day even though a car is perfectly aligned, various factors can encourage a pull in a particular direction including road camber and load distribution. That said in my experience setting wheel alignment has been one of the more complex jobs for the average mechanic - as a young man I watched a guy who had a high opinion of his own skills make a complete hash of a 4 wheel laser alignment; to me it was simple physics of laser beams and mirrors but the logic eluded him

Comment: You can even take a quick check of how your wheels are aligned yourself using a length of string, YouTube should have a few tutorials - i'd treat it as a check only, btw but it can give a simple visual verification that a laser alignment has been properly carried out

Comment: A string will only find toe issues, which cannot cause a pull.  A tire rotation on a modern car will have radials swapped front-to-back, never side-to-side.  Still, a bad tire moved to the back should not cause pull to one side.  Only camber and caster (and to a very slight degree thrust angle) misalignment can cause pull.  I would demand the alignment sheet printout as proof the alignment was done correctly.  Another possibility is a dragging brake caliper, in this case the right front.